# Could JDO talk to a SOAP service?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I've used JPA for a while. Having an entityManager that performs your SQL operations is great.

I've noticed that JDO (DataNucleous) goes beyond JPA and brings persistence to other datasources, XML among those

Not sure if I grasped the concept entirely correct, but I wonder if it could do something like SOAP.getObjectId(entity) then DB.makePersistent(entity) and viceversa, provided I can connect to SOAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way DataNucleus REST API works is that in your application you send/receive HTTP GET's/POST's of the form shown [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/rest/httpmethods.html) and these are translated into JDO calls to put/retrieve your data into/from the datastore. With that you can use any datastore that DataNucleus supports (so RDBMS, ODBMS, map-based, doc-based, etc).

Comment: Good examples that made me understand the way JDO works very clearly. Makes me wanna switch to REST as well. Thanks